# What is the correct syntax for a select query in drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

If I have a table named book

```
Column 1 = current_user
, Column 2 = page_length
, Column 3 = author
, Column 4 = title
```

I'd like to select the data from columns 2, 3 and 4 that correspond to the currently logged in user. Is the following correct syntax?

```
<?
global $user;
$user_id=$user->name;
db_query('SELECT * FROM {book} WHERE current_user=$user_id', $page_length, $author,   $title); ?>
```

Comment: First you must quot the query. But what you want to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

1. You need to make sure to use quotation marks around the string that is the SQL statement.
2. Since the username is a user-supplied string, you should use parameter escaping to prevent SQL injections.
3. You don't really need to assign the user name to a separate variable (`$user_id`) to use it.
4. You need to retrieve your result from the return value of `db_query`.

Fixed code:

```
<?php
global $user;
$res = db_query("SELECT page_length, author, title FROM {book} WHERE current_user = '%s'", $user->name); 
$row = db_fetch_array($res);
// now $row['page_length'], $row['author'] and $row['title'] are filled in with values if the query was successful
?>
```

Comment: So when i tried this, the query thinks that i have a column labeled as the user name (eg. student2, but it's just a value within a column named 'user_id'. SO i get the error "user warning: Unknown column 'student2' in 'where clause' query: ...."

Comment: ALSO, why is it ...current_user = %s", $user->name);?  it's unclear how current_user and $user->name are connected

Comment: also i know that student2 exists in the current_user column

Comment: $res = db_query("SELECT page_length, author, title FROM {book} WHERE current_user ='student2'");   works. $x = "student2" $res = db_query("SELECT page_length, author, title FROM {book} WHERE current_user =%s",$x);   fails

Comment: @ingrid I've updated my code, I was missing single quotes around the %s.
the `current_user = '%s'", $user->name);` happens because this is the secure way to create database queries. Basically that %s is a placeholder for the value contained in $user->name, `db_query` safely inserts that value so that hackers cannot take control of your database by feeding in carefully crafted user names.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why if there are multiple 'current_user' entries in the table, $row does not contain all possible values?

Comment: Because they are multiple rows. Each time you call `db_fetch_array` with the same `$res` will give you a different row from the result, you have to iterate over them: `while($row = db_fetch_array($res)) { /* do something with $row */ }`